# how to connect to nearest BLE devices

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

```
    -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    if (![discoverPeripherals containsObject:peripheral])
    {
        [discoverPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
        NSLog(@"rssi: %@", RSSI);
        [rssiArray addObject:RSSI];
        peripheral.delegate =self;
        NSNumber *max=[rssiArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
        NSLog(@"max.intValue: %@", max);
        int rssi=abs([[rssiArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue]);
        if (rssi<=40)
        {
            self.discoverPeripherals=peripheral;
            [CBManager connectPeripheral:self.currentPeripheral options:Nil];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<discoverPeripherals.count ; i++)
        {
            CBPeripheral *thisPeripheral =[discoverPeripherals objectAtIndex:i];
            if (thisPeripheral == peripheral)
            {
                [rssiArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:RSSI];
                NSLog(@"rssi: %@", RSSI);
            }
        }
```

Will you please help for connecting the nearest BLE device. I am able to get the rssi values but not connecting to them. Thank you

Comment: You don't seem to assign a value to `self.currentPeripheral` and you seem to be assigning a CBPeripheral to `self.discoverPeripherals` which I assume is an NSMutableArray variable. Finally, you are calling `connectPeriphal` on `CBCentral` which doesn't seem right

Comment: if (abs([peripheral.RSSI intValue]<40))
    {
        self.currentPeripheral=peripheral;
        [CBManager connectPeripheral:self.currentPeripheral options:Nil];
    }

Comment: i tried with above code. But not worked for me

Comment: Is this your actual code? as it has several errors that I noted in my previous comment.